# How to get IOwinContext from SignalR hub?

Tags: c#, .net, signalr, owin, signalr-hub

How to access `IOwinContext` from SignalR hub (for instance from `HubCallerContext`)?

Answer (score 4):

If you're on IIS, you can access the IOwinContext for the current connected client via the HubCallerContext (Context property of the Hub base class):

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using System.Web;

...

Context.Request.GetHttpContext().GetOwinContext()
```

[GetHttpContext is an extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.requestextensions.gethttpcontext(v=vs.111).aspx) under Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR and [GetOwinContext is an extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn270723(v=vs.113).aspx) under System.Web, so make sure you **import both of those namespaces** and **include the Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb assembly as a project reference**.

Comment: @TN. I'm not sure what you mean? It should be accessible in any non-static methods/properties in hubs that inherit from the base Hub class.

Comment: Owin is an abstraction layer which could be hosted in various environments (IIS, self-host, ...). When you write `System.Web` it looks like it it just for IIS hosting, it will not work in case of other environments.

Comment: GetHttpContext() is not available

Comment: @UjjwalKumarGupta Did you make sure to import the SignalR namespace via `using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;`?

Comment: yes,but there is no GetHttpContext() in the Context.request

Comment: From within which class are you attempting to access the property? Does it inherit from the SignalR base `Hub`?

Comment: @justis I'm kinda late, but I just bumped into this issue, `GetHttpContext()` is not available in `Hub`. I found 2 different pages for the `IRequest` interface [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.irequest(v=vs.111).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.irequest(v=vs.118).aspx). They refer to the same assembly, same namespace, but different extension methods.

Comment: [Here's the page on the Hub Context property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hub.context(v=vs.118).aspx), which returns a [HubCallerContext that provides a Request property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hubs.hubcallercontext(v=vs.118).aspx). Are you sure you went through `Context.Request.GetHttpContext()` rather than just `Context.GetHttpContext`? And that you're attempting to access it from an instance method in a class that inherits from Hub?